# Counting polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in the ideal $I = (x^5 + x^2 + x + 1,\; x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

> Suppose $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field of order $2$. Then let $$I = (x^5 + x^2 + x + 1, x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x)$$ be an ideal in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. How many polynomials of degree $3$ does $I$ contain?

There are $8$ such polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. Do we just check one by one if each of these is in $I$ by multiplying, adding and subtracting polynomials in $I$?

Or, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: $1$ is the only common root in $\mathbb F_2$ of both generators, so you could rule out any degree 3 polynomials that *do not* have $1$ as a root.

Comment: That rules out 4. What about the other 4?

Answer (score 1):

Using extended Euclid algorithm, you can see that the (monic) gcd of your two polynomials is $(x+1)^2$, so $I=((x+1)^2)$ (because $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is a PID).

Since multiplication by $(x+1)^2$ is injective ($\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is a domain), the number of polynomials of given degree $d\geq 2$ in $I$ is exactly the number of polynomials of degree $d-2$, that is $2^{d-2}$ (since you want your degree exactly equal to $d$, the coefficient of $X^d$ is already fixed to be $1$...)

More generally, the same reasoning shows that if $I=(f_1,\ldots,f_r)\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, the number of polynomials of $I$ of degree $d$ in $I$ equals $2^{d-e}$, where $e$ is the degree of a gcd of $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ (with the convention that $2^{d-e}=0$ if $d<e$).